# Magento 2 Mysql message queue not consuming the request

Tags: magento2, sales-order, message-queue, queue, consumers

I am using Magento 2.4 cloud. I've created a mysql asynchronous queue for order processing by following the link below.
https://erfanimani.com/using-magento-2-mysql-queue-for-order-post-processing
Here is my handler function

```
public function processOrder(string $orderId)
    {
        $writer = new \Zend_Log_Writer_Stream(BP . '/var/log/orderSyncResponse.log');
        $logger = new \Zend_Log();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        $logger->info('processOrder: '.$orderId);
        try {            
            $order = $this->orderRepository->get((int)$orderId);
            if ($order->getId()) {               
                $xmlData = $this->createXmlData($order);              
                $logger->info('Order ID: '.$order->getId());
                $logger->info(print_r($xmlData, true));
                $response = $this->postRequest($xmlData);
                $logger->info('Response: ');
                $logger->info(print_r($response, true));
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {            
            $logger->info($e->getMessage());           
            return;
        }
    }
```

I have configured the env.php as follows

```
 'queue' => 
  array (
    'consumers_wait_for_messages' => 1,
  ),
    
'cron_consumers_runner' => 
  array (
    'cron_run' => true,
    'max_messages' => 10000,
    'consumers' => 
    array (
    ),
    'multiple_processes' => 
    array (
    ),
  ),
```

The queue is working with the below command

> php bin/magento queue:consumers:start VendorOrderCreate
> --max-messages=1

But with the cron, the message queue started processing (ie, the 1st log is coming, then not processing). But it is not completing and shows the status as 3 in **queue_message_status** table.

Here is my log
[image]

Why this happens? Please help me to figure out this

Comment: put logger before $xmlData = $this->createXmlData($order); and check